# Display max year and its max month with their corresponding value in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
Year  Month Value
2015    1   300
2015    2   400
2010    4   100
2016    7   200
2016    8   300
2017    2   100
2017    3   200
2017    6   400
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a query that partially works?

Comment: Thanx its perfectly working :)

Comment: Question should indicate expected results. If the input has multiple rows that match max year and max month are you expecting multiple rows in the results set?

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following:

```
SELECT MAX(year), MAX(month)
     , MAX(value) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC )
  FROM mytable;
```

If you want the max month per year along with the corresponding value, then you can do this:

```
SELECT year, MAX(month)
     , MAX(value) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY month DESC )
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY year;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM tab t
      ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC) s
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: OP wants to have every individual year, but here we can get one row with values : `2017`,`6`,`400`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan `Display max year and its max month ` for me it is clear that it is one row, not max month per year

Comment: hm, a really strange question, then. Because of the word `corresponding`, i thought as every individual year ...

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table_name where month =
(select max(month) from table_name where year =
(select max(year) from table_name));

This might be the answer you are looking for, I have used nested queries to reach out to the desired result